# If I have an Authentication Filter from a WebAPI 2 project, can I reuse it in a WCF service?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-web-api2, restful-authentication

I built an authentication scheme and I have a `DelegatingHttpHandler` and `IAuthenticationFilter` that I use across a few Web API 2 services. I want to apply the same authentication to an older WCF service. Is there a reasonably easy way to reuse the authentication filter on a WCF service?

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way to reuse Authentication Filters on older WCF REST projects. Your best bet is to refactor the code into a class that both the WCF service and the WebApi Filter can both use.

Answer (score 0):

There is no straightforward way. But you can move the authentication logic to HttpModule and you can able to reuse the same module in both webapi and WCF projects